# TSQL How to manage find or handle duplicates

Tags: t-sql, duplicates

I have a query which is returning duplicates - How can I amend the query to prevent this or put a fix in place so this doe snot happen. I have tried using distinct but to no avail.

This is the query

```
select sigfind.*
from [RM-JOB] 
inner join  (
  select [JOB-NO], [LINK-JOB-NO] 
  from [RM-LINK-JOBS] 
  where [RM-LINK-JOBS].[reason-code] = 'FRA' 
) linkedjob on [RM-JOB].[JOB-NO] = linkedjob.[JOB-NO] 
inner join [RM-JOB] [RMLinkedJob] on linkedjob.[LINK-JOB-NO] = [RMLinkedJob].[JOB-NO] 
                                and [linkedjob].[JOB-NO] = [RM-JOB].[JOB-NO]
inner join (
  SELECT ar.JobNo, ar.[ActionRef], AR.ActionStatus, AR.ActionDueDate [LINKED VISIT TARGET DATE], ar.SignificantFindings [SignificantFindings], ar.SyncDate, ar.dateFirRiskIdentified [Date of FRA] , ard.caseref [Linked Case Number]
  FROM [CYHSQL01].[TM_FireRiskAssessment].[dbo].[ActionRequired] ar
  inner join [CYHSQL01].[TM_FireRiskAssessment].[dbo].[ActionRequireddetails] ard
        on AR.ResultID = ARD.ResultID and ard.actionref = ar.[ActionRef]
) sigfind on sigfind.JobNo = linkedjob.[JOB-NO]
where [RMLinkedJob].[JOB-TYPE] in ('FSRE') 
         and [RM-JOB].[JOB-STATUS] in ('06','90')
```

This is what the output is;

```
JobNo       ActionRef   ActionStatu LINKED VISIT                                                   TARGET DATE  SignificantFindings SyncDate    Date of FRA Linked Case Number
10265985    CP1 Closed  2019-01-18  Shoe cabinet is in the communal hallway door is a potential trip hazard when evacuating.    2019-10-18 11:11:41.457 2019-10-18  NULL
10265985    CP1 Closed  2019-01-18  Shoe cabinet is in the communal hallway door is a potential trip hazard when evacuating.    2019-10-18 11:11:41.457 2019-10-18  NULL
10265985    CP2 Closed  2019-10-25  Large screen tv has been fly tipped in the communal hallway.    2019-10-18 11:11:41.460 2019-10-18  NULL
10265985    CP2 Closed  2019-10-25  Large screen tv has been fly tipped in the communal hallway.    2019-10-18 11:11:41.460 2019-10-18  NULL
10265985    CP1 Closed  2019-01-18  Shoe cabinet is in the communal hallway door is a potential trip hazard when evacuating.    2019-10-18 11:11:41.457 2019-10-18  NULL
10265985    CP1 Closed  2019-01-18  Shoe cabinet is in the communal hallway door is a potential trip hazard when evacuating.    2019-10-18 11:11:41.457 2019-10-18  NULL
10265985    CP1 Closed  2019-01-18  Shoe cabinet is in the communal hallway door is a potential trip hazard when evacuating.    2019-10-18 11:11:41.457 2019-10-18  NULL
10265985    CP1 Closed  2019-01-18  Shoe cabinet is in the communal hallway door is a potential trip hazard when evacuating.    2019-10-18 11:11:41.457 2019-10-18  NULL
10265985    CP1 Closed  2019-01-18  Shoe cabinet is in the communal hallway door is a potential trip hazard when evacuating.    2019-10-18 11:11:41.457 2019-10-18  NULL
10265985    CP1 Closed  2019-01-18  Shoe cabinet is in the communal hallway door is a potential trip hazard when evacuating.    2019-10-18 11:11:41.457 2019-10-18  NULL
10265986    CP1 Closed  2019-10-28  There is a 5 litre petrol can stored under the stairs. This must be removed as a matter of urgency as it’s potentially highly flammable.    2019-10-21 13:05:56.533 2019-10-21  NULL
10265986    CP1 Closed  2019-10-28  There is a 5 litre petrol can stored under the stairs. This must be removed as a matter of urgency as it’s potentially highly flammable.    2019-10-21 13:05:56.533 2019-10-21  NULL
10265986    CP2 Open    2019-11-18  Shoe rack is being used in the communal area. This is a potential trip hazard in an evacuation situation.   2019-10-21 13:05:56.543 2019-10-21  NULL
10265986    CP2 Open    2019-11-18  Shoe rack is being used in the communal area. This is a potential trip hazard in an evacuation situation.   2019-10-21 13:05:56.543 2019-10-21  NULL
10265986    CP3 Open    2019-12-23  Christmas wreaths are a potential fire risk so must be removed. 2019-10-21 13:05:56.553 2019-10-21  Test Reference 12345
10265986    CP3 Open    2019-12-23  Christmas wreaths are a potential fire risk so must be removed. 2019-10-21 13:05:56.553 2019-10-21  Test Reference 12345
10265985    CP1 Closed  2019-01-18  Shoe cabinet is in the communal hallway door is a potential trip hazard when evacuating.    2019-10-18 11:11:41.457 2019-10-18  NULL
10265985    CP1 Closed  2019-01-18  Shoe cabinet is in the communal hallway door is a potential trip hazard when evacuating.    2019-10-18 11:11:41.457 2019-10-18  NULL
```

Could I use a windowing function to remove duplicates? I would be using JobNo, ActionRef and Syncdate to produce a number 1 and filter on that?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Do you think you can format your SQL sensibly so that it becomes readable and does not require scrolling?

Comment: you don't have duplicates -- you are only looking at one of the tables -- if you look at all of the tables in the results you willl find the field that has the duplicate.  Then you will know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Your duplicates may be caused by join conditions, although I have to admit I have troubles to understand your SQL code. If adding distinct between **select** and **sigfind.*** does not work try to put whole code into WITH clause and then select distinct.

```
with myResult as (
    Your Query here
)
select distinct column1, column2, ..., columnX from myResult
```

It might be better to go thru your query logic, fix it a try to make it more readable .